# How could I implement whether or not a tarot card is upright or reversed?

Tags: python

I modified the FrenchDeck class from Fluent Python by Luciano Ramalho to try to build a tarot deck. Since tuples are immutable I can't store whether or not the card is reversed in the tuple so I implemented an orientation as shown below.

```
import collections
from random import getrandbits

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank','suit'])

class FrenchTarot:
  ranks = [str(n) for n in range(1,11)]+['Page','Knight','Queen','King']
  suits = 'wands swords coins cups'.split()
  major_arcana = ['The Fool', 'The Magician', 'The High Priestess', 'The Empress',
                  'The Hierophant', 'The Lovers', 'The Chariot', 'Strength',
                  'The Hermit', 'Wheel of Fortune', 'Justice', 'The Hanged Man',
                  'Death', 'Temperance', 'The Devil', 'The Tower', 'The Star',
                  'The Moon', 'The Sun', 'Judgement', 'The World']

  def __init__(self):
    self.minor = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]
    self.major = [Card(rank, 'Major Arcana') for rank in self.major_arcana]
    self._cards = self.major + self.minor

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self._cards)

  def __repr__(self):
    return f'Tarot Deck containing {len(self)} cards, {len(self.major)} Major Arcana, and {len(self.minor)} Minor Arcana'

  def __getitem__(self,position):
    if getrandbits(1):
      orientation = 'Upright'
    else:
      orientation = 'Reversed'
    return self._cards[position], orientation

  def __setitem__(self, position, card):
    self._cards[position] = card
```

The problem here comes when I try to test

```
Card('The Fool', 'Major Arcana') in deck
```

it returns False and the only way to get it to return True would be to specify the orientation (and randomly guess correctly). I'm not sure how to approach the problem associate each card with an orientation that could randomly be changed when a card is pulled

edit: so sorry posted the wrong code block at first oops

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you define `deck` is it meant to be `_cards`?

Comment: deck is just an instantiated instance of the class

Comment: Have you looked into dataclasses instead of namedtuples?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `card in deck`, but `in` doesn't behave the way you want, you can override that behavior with the `__contains__` magic method. This would enable you to write a custom test that ignores the orientation attribute.

You can also make a `Card` class that overrides `__eq__` to compare their rank and suit but ignore their orientation so that you can use `==` intuitively.

Comment: Added `def __contains__(self, card):return card in self._cards` and it works perfectly, thanks